# Selecting and displaying api data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, openweathermap

I'm trying to display weather forecase data from the openweathermap API - When I run this code and click my submit button, it displays "undefined" on my page.

```
var api_key = "&APPID=c0aa3c8995df1b0dd97032d0072333b3";
var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=";
var city = "Toronto";
var units = "&units=metric"

$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
    input = $('#city');
    $(function(){
        var url = api + input.val() + api_key + units;
        $.getJSON(url, function(wd){
            document.write(JSON.stringify(wd.list.main));
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: How does `wd` look like? the `wd.list.main` might be undefined

Comment: The API returns the correct structure (I called it in my browser). The returned object may need to be parsed back into a JSON object before you can use it. Console wd, wd.list and check the type of both.

Comment: `wd.list` is an array when i run http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Toronto&APPID=c0aa3c8995df1b0dd97032d0072333b3&units=metric
So `wd.list.main` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

List is an array, you should access it like so

```
wd.list[0].main.temp
```

Also, no need to use stringify, this worked fine for me

```
document.write(wd.list[0].main.temp);
```

Here it is in a loop, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/21370/)

```
var api_key = "&APPID=c0aa3c8995df1b0dd97032d0072333b3";
var api = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=";
var units = "&units=metric"

$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
    input = $("#city");
    $(function(){
        var url = api + input.val() + api_key + units;
        $.getJSON(url, function(wd){
            var list = wd.list;
            $.each(list, function(i,v) {
                 document.write("Timestamp: " + v.dt + " " + "Temp: " + v.main.temp + " " + "Min: " + v.main.temp_min + " " + "Max: " + v.main.temp_max + " " + "Pressure: " + v.main.pressure + "<br />");
            });
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: The entries in the `wd.list` array is the weather forcast for Toronto on a 3 hour interval for the next 5 days. Nice of you to reflect that!

Comment: Can't see your results in the fiddle!

Comment: @jgerofsky It works fine here.. Just type "Toronto" and click submit. The text is dark, maybe hard to see on your screen.. Try this one https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/21371/

Comment: @jgerofsky Also worth noting that I noticed the geocoding tends to be a bit finicky about commas and misspellings. Try a zip code.. that seems to work much better. Might be worth using a better geocoding api (like google) and send the zip code to the weather api in the future